# Core Data - filter entity and its relationship field

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

Suppose I have a core data model like this one:

[image]

This are the NSManagedObject:

```
class Day: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var date: String
    @NSManaged var daynews: NSSet
}

class News: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var content: String
    @NSManaged var type: String
    @NSManaged var day: Day
}
```

So I have a one to many relationship between Day and News: a day is related with some news. Each news has a type:

1. morning
2. evening

I want to be able to fetch all days with news of a specific type, and on these day filter the daynews field so that it contains only the news of this specific type.
For example:

```
Day1 has News1{type:"morning", content:"..."} and News2{type:"evening", content:"..."}.
Day2 has News3{type:"morning", content:"..."} and News4{type:"morning", content:"..."}.
Day3 has News5{type:"morning", content:"..."} and News6{type:"evening", content:"..."}.
```

In this case if a try to filter with type="evening", I want to get Day1 and Day3, and in the field daynews have only News2 for Day1 and News6 for Day3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When fetching days, use this predicate in your fetch request:

```
let filter = NSPredicate(format: "ANY daynews.type = %@", "morning")
request.predicate = filter
```

When displaying the news for the day, use

```
day.daynews.filteredSetUsingPredicate(filter)
```

You could put a convenience method for this into you managed object subclass.